# R - Fitting a model per subject using data.table or dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, model-fitting

I have a set of observations for many subjects and I would like to fit a model for each subject.

I"m using the packages `data.table` and `fitdistrplus`, but could also try to use `dlpyr`.

Say my data are of this form:

```
#subject_id #observation
1           35
1           38
2           44
2           49
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
 subject_models <- dt[,fitdist(observation, "norm", method = "mme"), by=subject_id]
```

This causes an error I think because the call to `fitdist` returns a `fitdist` object which is not possible to store in a datatable/dataframe.

Is there any intuitive way to do this using `data.table` or `dplyr`?

**EDIT:** A dplyr answer was provided, but I would appreciate a data.table one as well, I'll try to run some benchmarks against the two.

Comment: Stick the model in a list column till you can simplify it. [Here's a video about doing it in the tidyverse.](http://edinbr.org/edinbr/2016/05/11/may-Hadley-Update2-PostingTalk.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily achieved with the `purrr` package

I assume its the same thing @alistaire suggested

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(fitdistrplus)
dt %>% split(dt$subject_id) %>%  map( ~ fitdist(.$observation, "norm", method = "mme"))
```

Alternatively, without `purrr`,

```
dt %>% split(dt$subject_id) %>%  lapply(., function(x) fitdist(x$observation, "norm", method = "mme"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sumedh. Is there an easy way to parallelize the map call within R/dplyr?

Comment: @Bar, I don't enough about parallelization in R to respond

Comment: @Bar per your comment about how to parallelize -- you may want to open a new question, showing this technique and then showing what you have tried as an attempt to parallelize.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns sure, I'll open one now.