# R - Parallelizing multiple model learning (with dplyr and purrr)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, dplyr, purrr

This is a follow up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38230957/209882) about learning multiple models.

The use case is that I have multiple observations for each subject, and
I want to train a model for each of them. See Hadley's [excellent presentation](http://edinbr.org/edinbr/2016/05/11/may-Hadley-Update2-PostingTalk.html) on how to do this.

In short, this is possible to do using `dplyr` and `purrr` like so:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(fitdistrplus)
dt %>% 
    split(dt$subject_id) %>%
    map( ~ fitdist(.$observation, "norm"))
```

So since the model building is an embarrassingly parallel task, I was
wondering if `dplyr`, `purrr` have an easy to use parallelization mechanism for such tasks (like a parallel `map`).

If these libraries don't provide easy parallelization could it be done using the classic R parallelization libraries (`parallel`, `foreach` etc)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is the [`furrr`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=furrr) package now, for example something like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(furrr)
plan(multisession)   # or perhaps:  plan(multicore), see ?plan

dt %>% 
    split(dt$subject_id) %>%
    future_map(~fitdist(.$observation, "norm"))
```

Answer (score 13):

Just adding an answer for completeness here, you will need to install [multidplyr](https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr/) from Hadley's repo to run this, more info in the [vignette](https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr/blob/master/vignettes/multidplyr.md):

```
library(dplyr)
library(multidplyr)
library(purrr)

cluster <- create_cluster(4)
set_default_cluster(cluster)
cluster_library(cluster, "fitdistrplus")

# dt is a dataframe, subject_id identifies observations from each subject
by_subject <- partition(dt, subject_id)

fits <- by_subject %>% 
    do(fit = fitdist(.$observation, "norm")))

collected_fits <- collect(fits)$fit
collected_summaries <- collected_fits %>% map(summary)
```

Comment: multidplyr hasn't been developed for 2 years (as of Aug 2018) so something like furrr might be better.